# LaTeX figure labeling in tables

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

I have 6 figures in a 2x3 table which, inclucing the caption, fill one page nicely. I would like to label them with a), b), c) at the top left of every row. I experimented with subfigures, but didn't get it done. In some way, the `caption` package also conflicts with the `subcaption` package. This is what I have at the moment. I appreciate any hints!

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{1}} & 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{2}} \\
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{3}} & 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{4}} \\
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{5}} & 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{6}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{x}
\label{x}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The `caption` package definitely does *not* conflict with the `subcaption` package, instead the `subcaption` package is actually using a feature offered by the `caption` package, and both packages are part of the same LaTeX package bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PS: Do you mean 2x3 or 3x2? You said you need to create 2x3 but the code your gave is for 3x2.* Anyway, I will give methods for both ways.

---

## For 3x2:

You can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\subfloat[configuration 1]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{8}}\par
\subfloat[configuration 2]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{9}}\par
\subfloat[configuration 3]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{7}}\newpage
\subfloat[configuration 4]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{8}}\par
\subfloat[configuration 5]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{9}}\par
\subfloat[configuration 6]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{8}}
\end{multicols}
\caption{Here goes the caption.}
\label{fig6}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which will give:

[image]

## For 2x3:

You can delete `caption` package, `subfig` alone is enough. And there are two ways to go:

1. Using table:

   ```
   \begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{ccc}
   \subfloat[configuration 1]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}} &
   \subfloat[configuration 2]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{9}} &
   \subfloat[configuration 3]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{7}} \\
   \subfloat[configuration 4]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}} &
   \subfloat[configuration 5]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{9}} &
   \subfloat[configuration 6]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}}
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{Here goes the caption.}
   \label{fig6}
   \end{figure}
   ```
2. Without using table:

   ```
   \begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
   \subfloat[configuration 1]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}}
   \subfloat[configuration 2]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{9}}
   \subfloat[configuration 3]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{7}}
   \hspace{\textwidth}
   \subfloat[configuration 4]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}}
   \subfloat[configuration 5]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{9}}
   \subfloat[configuration 6]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}}
   \caption{Here goes the cpation.}
   \end{figure}
   ```

Both will get something like:

[image]

Comment: I meant 3x2, but it doesn't matter, this answer was helpful already. I'd prefer to label each of the three rows at the top left of the left image, is this in any way possible?

Comment: @user3201742 I don't see this possible as row-major order is used for table figures.

Comment: @user3201742 I just realized a way to do this. See updated.